# What are the longest range chaos actives?

Tags: the-secret-world

What are the longest range chaos active abilities in secret world? Most are short range like Run Rampant, but I'm looking for something to complement my assault rifle with a bit of range, especially for a resource consuming attack.

Comment: I don't really think any of them have substantial range...in fact, might *all* be melee range.  I haven't played with every ability so don't hold me to that...I think if you're looking for ranged DPS this is probably not the best idea, though.

Comment: Pulling the strings has a 7m range, so I was wanting to know if any other skills have an "unstated" range. =)

Comment: I hadn't run with that, so there you go.  It seems like most melee things have at least one decent ranged attack, but that very well might be it.  Honestly, I'd question why you want to use Chaos for ranged anyway...?

Comment: In pvp generally you run into situations where a player will be running around you in circles or pulling back, in which case you want something that's PBAoE or has a short range to keep up with them. I've been experimenting with a AR/chaos build, the AR part has problems with the circles and the chaos part has problems with the pulling back, so I'm thinking of switching to AR/blade as soon as I can afford to get a purple. =)

Comment: Oh, I forget people still do PvP because it's so poorly balanced right now...I know if I jump into Fusang it's 100% Templar all the time and I can't even make it out of my base. :/  It might make more sense in that context, yes.

Comment: On arcadia at least it tends to cycle between Templar and Dragon with Illuminati making an appearance in the lead every once in a while.